# pydev test runner error: imported unittest before running pytest.main

Tags: python, eclipse

I am trying to run a pytest on eclipse for the below code:

```
def func(x):
return x + 1
def test_answer():
assert func(3) == 5
```

Expected result got displayed on the console. But with an error: **pydev test runner error: imported unittest before running pytest.main**.
Please let me know how can I remove this error

Entire result is:

```
pydev test runner error: imported unittest before running pytest.main
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.6.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: D:\Eclipse1\TFCProject, inifile:
collected 1 item

TFCPackage\pycheck.py F                                                  [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________________________ test_answer _________________________________

    def test_answer():
>       assert func(3) == 5
E       assert 4 == 5
E        +  where 4 = func(3)

TFCPackage\pycheck.py:10: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.35 seconds ===========================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already fixed in github/master.

The problem is that pydev checked that it did not inadvertently import unittest when using the pytest runner and gave that message when that happened, but recently pytest itself started to import unittest internally (thus making the behavior that pydev tried to prevent something that always happens by default).

So, the next release should have that fixed (6.3.4).